# import com.google.android

Tags: android, google-maps

I can't import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment

I read some topics and I cant' find the solution.

I chose google api's in propreties > android

I add  in my manifest > application

and I import

C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\add-ons\addon-google_apis-google-8\libs\maps.jar

to my project

Thanks

Comment: had you got the MD5 finger print of your PC from google?

Comment: You will have to use your MD5 finger print to get the APIKey.

Comment: yes did you get the API Key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Right Click on maps.jar->Build Path-> Add to Build Path
```

it might work.

Answer (score 1):

I faced same issues, later found that google-play-sevices-lib ( `android-sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib`
 ) project is not added as library project.